# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 6898: invalid start byte-Reading file using Argument Parser in Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing, word-embedding

I am implementing code from this link [Glove implementation](https://github.com/hans/glove.py/blob/master/glove.py)
I am reading a file from the specified path using ArgumentParser in Python.

```
parser.add_argument('corpus', metavar='corpus_path',
                        type=partial(codecs.open, encoding='utf-8'))
```

I am using this command in command prompt to pass arguments

```
python Glove_python_bbc.py "C:/Users/JAYASHREE/Documents/NLP/text-corpus.txt" --vocab-path C:/Users/JAYASHREE/Documents/NLP/vocabulary --cooccur-path C:/Users/JAYASHREE/Documents/NLP/cooccur_matrix -w 10 --min-count 10 --vector-path C:/Users/JAYASHREE/Documents/NLP/word-vector -s 40 --iterations 10 --learning-rate 0.1 --save-often
```

But I am getting the following error

```
2017-08-06 23:03:46,171 Fetching vocab..
2017-08-06 23:03:46,171 Building vocab from corpus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Glove_python_bbc.py", line 383, in <module>
    main(parse_args())
  File "Glove_python_bbc.py", line 352, in main
    vocab = get_or_build(arguments.vocab_path, build_vocab, corpus)
  File "Glove_python_bbc.py", line 93, in get_or_build
    obj = build_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Glove_python_bbc.py", line 112, in build_vocab
    for line in corpus:
  File "C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\codecs.py", line 699, in next
    return self.reader.next()
  File "C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\codecs.py", line 630, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\codecs.py", line 545, in readline
    data = self.read(readsize, firstline=True)
  File "C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\codecs.py", line 492, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 6898: invalid start byte
```

The screenshot of the file which I am trying to read [image: Screenshot of text-corpus.txt]

Comment: It looks like the data you're reading isn't encoded with UTF-8. You need to find out what the actual encoding is, and specify that in your `encoding` arg.

Comment: Are you sure that `text-corpus.txt` is utf-8 encoded?

Comment: There are a number of encodings, such as `latin-1` and `cp1252`, that decode `b'\xa3'` to `£`. You might try those (e.g. [`type=argparse.FileType('r', encoding='latin-1')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects)) and see if the rest of the text is correct.

Comment: I did not encode the file properly in utf-8.Found the bug in my code.Thanks for your suggestions.